# Xcode iOS instrumented testing without a UI?

Tags: ios, xcode, testing

I have a unique situation where my IOS app UI will be taken care of through a different UI engine, which will be communicating with an underlying library to call through the mobile stack.

In order to test the library integration into the mobile stack and validate no issues will occur, I would like to run my tests in a similar manner to android. Where I provide the tests and they run through an android stack without a UI.

I have attempted to write a UI test without an UI in Xcode (which sounds like it would break) and it broke (who would have guessed?!). So my questions is how do I write an instrumented test without a UI - since this library is cross platform.

I'm open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use xctest and write logical tests. **Logical tests** i.e. library tests are similar to instrumented testing as available in android.

From apple documentation:

> Xcode offers two types of unit test contexts: app tests and library
> tests.
>
> 1. **App tests**. App tests check the correct behavior of code in your app,
>    such as the example of the calculator app’s arithmetic operations.
> 2. **Library tests**. Library tests check the correct behavior of code in
>    dynamic libraries and frameworks independent of their use in an app’s
>    runtime. With library tests you construct unit tests that exercise the
>    components of a library. Testing your projects using these test
>    contexts as appropriate helps you maintain expected and anticipated
>    behavior as your code evolves over time.
>
> source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/03-testing_basics.html

The best example for this is the calculator app provided by apple. Here is the link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/02-quick_start.html

The link might explain the application tests but the app source code has both tests.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/UnitTests/Listings/Shared_CalculatorLogicTests_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011742-Shared_CalculatorLogicTests_m-DontLinkElementID_11

See below a snippet from the app source code:

```
/* The setUp method is called automatically before each test-case method (methods whose name starts with 'test').
 */
- (void) setUp {
   NSLog(@"%@ setUp", self.name);
   calculator = [[Calculator alloc] init];
   XCTAssertNotNil(calculator, @"Cannot create Calculator instance");
}
 
 
/* The tearDown method is called automatically after each test-case method (methods whose name starts with 'test').
 */
- (void) tearDown {
   NSLog(@"%@ tearDown", self.name);
}
 
/* testAddition performs a simple addition test: 6 + 2 = 8.
 * The test has two parts:
 * 1. Through the input: method, feed the calculator the characters 6, +, 2, and =.
 * 2. Confirm that displayValue is 8.
 */
- (void) testAddition {
   NSLog(@"%@ start", self.name);   // self.name is the name of the test-case method.
   [calculator input:@"6"];
   [calculator input:@"+"];
   [calculator input:@"2"];
   [calculator input:@"="];
   XCTAssertTrue([[calculator displayValue] isEqualToString:@"8"], @"");
   NSLog(@"%@ end", self.name);
}
```

- setUp : This is called before the test is executed
- tearDown: This is called after the test is finished
- testAddition: This is the test case which checks if the calculator library is correctly performing the addition.

Comment: I might not have been clear. 

You are providing the simple testing information for a new test. 

There is a complicated issue, where you cannot test a background thread, without creating a ui. I would like to test a library but the ios app will fail without a built ui, which is annoying considering the library is meant to be built as a cocoapod and therefore should not be modified. 

Maybe I wasn't clear, but thank you for trying.

Comment: Logical tests do not run through the mobile app stack.

Comment: Totally confused on what is your requirement and what isnt working with logical or application tests. Logical test can test a library without using app UI. Application test can test the app.

Comment: Logical tests test an application without a ui by running the tests through swift WITHOUT going through an ios stack. Which means that it's equivalent to testing android components using just java. The mobile application stack is not used for these tests.

Application tests run through the emulator and therefore are used for integration testing on the mobile platform. This is my goal. On android I can make calls through dalvik without producing a ui to verify it works through the android stack. On IOS I haven't found a way to do so as of now. If I wanted to test a library...

Comment: It seems as If I'll need to produce a test harness ui and import the library via cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, It doesn't seem to be possible to run service or library tests through the application testing framework without a ui. What my team and I have decided to do is create a test harness that import a cocoapod that we created that is regularly built with latest changes from github. So this test harness will always have latest library code, and we can modify the ui for our testing purposes.

I will update if I find a better solution in my studies. Currently, this is only way we can get it working.